# Github API Returning null repository language

Tags: github-api

For some reason github API returns `null` as language for all **my** repositories while repositories I forked are just fine. It detects language just fine on github website though.

Anyone has a clue why is this so?

Here is my request location: https://api.github.com/users/igorpan/repos

As you can see, wherever `'fork': true`, language is provided. But wherever fork is false it is `null`.

And here is my profile: https://github.com/igorpan?tab=repositories . Languages are recognized just fine on repository list.

Comment: This looks more like a bug than anything else. You might want to contact GitHub support

Comment: I did but unfortunately they haven't answered anything.

Comment: It sometimes takes a few days for them to respond. But don't worry - they will.

Comment: Pro tip: Always put "API" in the subject line. Then the guys who work on the API will see it sooner and get back to you faster. They API team at GitHub is pure awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sent an email to their support and they replied. It was caching issue on their end and they manually invalidated my repositories' cache so everything is fine now.